# Populate a custom objects' array without wrapping it in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

As mentioned, I declared this array:

```
var Questionari:[Questionario]!
```

Then I'll try to fill it:

```
for questionario in questionari{
    let q=Questionario.init(json: questionario)               
    self.Questionari!.append(q!)                     
}
```

Having result this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

If I try, instead, to fill it in this way:

```
var Questionari:[Questionario]?
for questionario in questionari{
    let q=Questionario.init(json: questionario)                
    self.Questionari?.append(q!)

}
```

Will work with no error, but the array will still stay empty (it will be nil in every cycle iteration, as seen by the debugger).

Comment: I think questionari  array is empty so getting  error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `questionari` array is declared but not initialized.

You have to initialize it (as non-optional):

```
var questionari = [Questionario]()
```

You can populate it safely with the `flatMap` function. It ignores `nil` values.
A loop is not needed:

```
self.questionari = questionari.flatMap { Questionario(json: $0) }
```

Side note: Variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter (then perhaps you might have to rename the local `questionari` array).

Comment: Thanks a lot and yes: you're right. Being not MAC common user isn't helpful.

Comment: Just For Information ,is it performance is faster then loop ??

Comment: Those functions are optimized. `flatMap` is certainly faster than a loop including a `nil` check.

Answer (score 1):

As @vaidan answer you have to initialize questionari  array,
and to unwrap Questionario object
Replace this line

```
 let q=Questionario.init(json: questionario)

                                self.Questionari!.append(q!)
```

with

```
 if let q=Questionario.init(json: questionario)
  {   self.Questionari.append(q)}
```